# isMemberOfClass doesn't work as expected with ocunit

Tags: objective-c, ios, ocunit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['isMemberOfClass' returning 'NO' when custom init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692854/ismemberofclass-returning-no-when-custom-init)

I've some trouble with the "isMemberOfClass"-Method.

I have a class, that generates and returns objects ("`MyObject`")

```
// ObjectFactory.h
...
-(MyObject*)generateMyObject;
...

// ObjectFactory.m
...
-(MyObject*)generateMyObject
{
    MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc]init];
    obj.name = @"Whatever";      // set properties of object
    return obj;
}
...
```

And there's a unittest-class, that calls the `generateMyObject`-selector and checks the class of the returned object:

```
...
ObjectFactory *factory = [[ObjectFactory alloc]init];
MyObject *obj = [factory generateMyObject];
if (![obj isMemeberOfclass:[MyObject class]])
    STFail(@"Upps, object of wrong class returned...");
else
...
```

I expect, that the `else`-part is processed...but the STFail(...) is called instead, but why?

Thx for any help!
Regards,
matrau

Ok, here is the original copy&pasted code:

```
//testcase
- (void)test001_setCostumeFirstCostume
{
    NSString *xmlString = @"<Bricks.SetCostumeBrick><costumeData reference=\"../../../../../costumeDataList/Common.CostumeData\"/><sprite reference=\"../../../../..\"/></Bricks.SetCostumeBrick>";
    NSError *error;
    NSData *xmlData = [xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData
                                                           options:0 error:&error];
    SetCostumeBrick *newBrick = [self.parser loadSetCostumeBrick:doc.rootElement];
    if (![newBrick isMemberOfClass:[SetCostumeBrick class]])
        STFail(@"Wrong class-member");
}

// "MyObject"
@implementation SetCostumeBrick
@synthesize indexOfCostumeInArray = _indexOfCostumeInArray;

- (void)performOnSprite:(Sprite *)sprite fromScript:(Script*)script
{
    NSLog(@"Performing: %@", self.description);

    [sprite performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(changeCostume:) withObject:self.indexOfCostumeInArray waitUntilDone:true];
}

- (NSString*)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SetCostumeBrick (CostumeIndex: %d)", self.indexOfCostumeInArray.intValue];
}

@end

// superclass of SetCostumeBrick
@implementation Brick
- (NSString*)description
{
    return @"Brick (NO SPECIFIC DESCRIPTION GIVEN! OVERRIDE THE DESCRIPTION METHOD!";
}

//abstract method (!!!)
- (void)performOnSprite:(Sprite *)sprite fromScript:(Script*)script
{
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                                   reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You must override %@ in a subclass", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)]
                                 userInfo:nil];
}
@end

// the "factory" (a xml-parser)
- (SetCostumeBrick*)loadSetCostumeBrick:(GDataXMLElement*)gDataSetCostumeBrick
{
    SetCostumeBrick *ret = [[SetCostumeBrick alloc] init];

    NSArray *references = [gDataSetCostumeBrick elementsForName:@"costumeData"];
    GDataXMLNode *temp = [(GDataXMLElement*)[references objectAtIndex:0]attributeForName:@"reference"];
    NSString *referencePath = temp.stringValue;

    if ([referencePath length] > 2)
    {
        if([referencePath hasSuffix:@"]"]) //index found
        {
            NSString *indexString = [referencePath substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([referencePath length]-2, 1)];
            ret.indexOfCostumeInArray = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexString.intValue-1];
        }
        else 
        {
            ret.indexOfCostumeInArray = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        ret.indexOfCostumeInArray = nil;
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                                       reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Parser error! (#1)"]
                                     userInfo:nil];
    }

    NSLog(@"Index: %@, Reference: %@", ret.indexOfCostumeInArray, [references objectAtIndex:0]);

    return ret;
}
```

SOLUTION:

Eiko/jrturton gave me a link to the solution - thx: [isMemberOfClass returns no when ViewController is instantiated from UIStoryboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675256/ismemberofclass-returns-no-when-viewcontroller-is-instantiated-from-uistoryboard)

The problem was, that the classes were included in both targets (app and test bundle)

Thank you guys for your help :)

Comment: Please use copy-paste... that code has obvious spelling mistakes in method names.

Comment: Try debugging and watching obj class.

Comment: Can you show the `init` method of the `MyObject` class? Does it actually return a `MyObject` or perhaps some subclass instance?

Comment: Ok, sry, I'll copy&paste next time...

there's no explicit init-method (is this the issue??)

Comment: What is the output of `NSLog(@"%@", [obj class])` ?

Comment: debug-result (@if-line):
(lldb) po [obj class]
(id) $1 = 0x00066968 MyObject

Comment: Please show the output of `[newBrick class]` and `[SetCostumeBrick class]`.

Comment: [newBrick class] => 'SetCostumeBrick'

[SetCostumeBrick class] => 'SetCostumeBrick'

Comment: Very strange ... or I am blind and miss the obvious. Can you show the debugger output of "po [newBrick class]" and "po [SetCostumeBrick class]", including the addresses?

Comment: (lldb) po [newBrick class]
(id) $1 = 0x00066a84 SetCostumeBrick

Comment: (lldb) po [SetCostumeBrick class]
(id) $2 = 0x00066a84 SetCostumeBrick

Comment: What's the debugger say about isMemberOfClass and isKindOfClass on those?

Comment: [newBrick class] => '0x66a84'    [SetCostumeBrick class] => '0x7aaf82c'

Comment: Aha!  Was that from printing %p (the comment I deleted because the debugger seemed to indicate it was useless)?

Comment: Are you using KVO, or anything else that may be doing IsA-swizzling?

Comment: What about this?  

`NSLog(@"className: %s", class_getName([newBrick class]);`

Comment: no KVO - I don't think so..........Output: className: SetCostumeBrick

Comment: Is that true copy and paste now? There is no else part...

Comment: I am also confused. `[SetCostumeBrick class]` is 0x00066a84 in one comment and 0x7aaf82c in another comment.

Comment: "else" is "do nothing, unit-test is ok... there is no explicit else-part................0x7aaf834 is the output of NSLog(@"%p", [SetCostumeBrick class]); ........ 0x00066a84 is the debugger-output of "po [SetCostumeBrick class]"

Comment: You're right jrturton, I found the solution there => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675256/ismemberofclass-returns-no-when-viewcontroller-is-instantiated-from-uistoryboard Thanks to all for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with different class addresses per your comment, I think I can track this down to be a duplicate of this:

[isMemberOfClass returns no when ViewController is instantiated from UIStoryboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675256/ismemberofclass-returns-no-when-viewcontroller-is-instantiated-from-uistoryboard)

Basically, your class is included twice.

Comment: This should be a close as duplicate vote, not an answer.

Comment: @jrurton I thought so as well at first, but then, there is more "debugging information" in this post than in the other - hence I think this question should receive a proper answer (which obviously links back to the longer original answer).

Answer (score 2):

You generally want isKindOfClass:, not isMemberOfClass. The isKindOfClass: will return YES if the receiver is a member of a subclass of the class in question, whereas isMemberOfClass: will return NO in the same case.

```
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[MyObject class]])
```

For example,

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray array];
```

Here `[array isMemberOfClass:[NSArray class]]` will return NO but `[array isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]` will return YES.

Comment: That's wrong. isKindOfClass tests with subclasses as well, and here clearly isMemberOfClass should work as well.

Comment: That's true but I thought the sub-classing might be the issue. Added details.

Comment: `init` methods need not return `self`, they can return some other object, e.g. an instance of a subclass. We don't know if that is the case here, but if it is, applefreak has given the right answer.

Comment: @Eiko In the case of `NSArray` the method `isMemberOfClass` returns NO because of the class cluster.  For me, `NSLog(@"%@", [array class])` returns `__NSArrayI` which is not `NSArray`.  Therefore, `isMemberOfClass` returns NO, whereas `isKindOfClass` returns YES.  I think this is a distraction from the OPs question though as their MyObject class is unlikely to be a class cluster so `isMemberOfClass` should work.

Comment: @mttrb I know all the details, and for this specific question the answer just doesn't make sense. It's perfectly fine to suggest isKindOfClass: as a comment, but as it cannot solve the problem, it is no answer.

Comment: @Eiko I misunderstood your original comment.  I read "and here clearly iMemberOfClass should work" as referring to this answer not to the OP's original question.