# Test for class type says two classes aren't the same when they appear to be the same

Tags: ios, objective-c, testing

On iOS, I'm using Expecta to test that a certain object's property is of the correct class. Here's my Expecta expectation:

`expect(splashController.reachabilityHUD).to.beKindOf([MBProgressHUD class]);`

The code under test is:

`self.reachabilityHUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];`

The error returned by the test is:

`expected: a kind of MBProgressHUD, got an instance of MBProgressHUD, which is not a kind of MBProgressHUD`

As expected, if I drop into `lldb`, I get the following:

```
(lldb) po [splashController.reachabilityHUD class]
MBProgressHUD
(lldb) po [MBProgressHUD class]
MBProgressHUD
```

I then throw this into the test:

```
Class actualClass = [splashController.reachabilityHUD class];
Class expectedClass = [MBProgressHUD class];
```

I print the same output in `lldb`. However, the variables view now shows:

```
expectedClass = (Class) 0x9e58f98
actualClass = (Class) MBProgressHUD
```

Why is this occurring?

Comment: This is the same problem as [isMemberOfClass returns no when ViewController is instantiated from UIStoryboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675256/ismemberofclass-returns-no-when-viewcontroller-is-instantiated-from-uistoryboard)

Comment: Indeed it is--thanks for the pointer, @JoshCaswell!